# how does df.copy() work when you use .remove on a row data with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, copy

I am trying to make a copy of my df to delete data from the copy without affecting the original, but with all the tests I have done, it always changes the copy and the original. Here is the code:

```
import copy
data = {"name": [["Sally", "EYE", "FACE"], ["Mary", "John"]]],
    "qualified": [True, False]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = copy.deepcopy(df)
#new_df = df.copy() #new_df = df.copy(deep=True)
for i in range(0, len(new_df)):
    for j in new_df['name'][i]:
       new_df['name'][i].remove(j)         
print("\nNEWDF: ", newdf)
print("\nDF: ", df)
```

RESULT:

- NEW_DF:

```
           name  qualified
    0   [EYE]       True
    1  [John]      False
```

- DF:

```
           name  qualified
    0   [EYE]       True
    1  [John]      False
```

Doing this always modifies the original, why doesn't it modify only the copy?

I have tried to solve it using:

- new_df = copy.deepcopy(df)
- new_df = df.copy()
- new_df = df.copy(deep=True)

and using the original instead of the copy. The result is always the same.

I want it to come out:

- DF:

```
                     name  qualified
    0  [Sally, EYE, FACE]       True
    1        [Mary, John]      False
```

- NEW_DF:

```
           name  qualified
    0   [EYE]       True
    1  [John]      False
```

Comment: I don't know the answer - but I can add the following: After the deepcopy line u can already see that something went wrong by calling id(df["name"].iloc[0]) and id(new_df["name"].iloc[0]). They refer to the same object

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a deepcopy via first creating a dict and calling deepcopy on the dict (don't know y deepcopy on df does not work properly):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(copy.deepcopy(df.to_dict()))
```

Edit:

If you read the reference for the pandas copy method: It says that for python objects no deep copy is performed. Now, calling the python deepcopy delegates to a **deepcopy** attribute of the NDFrame class. This may explain as to why in both cases you don't get a regular deepcopy.

Comment: Look at: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html . This explains why the pandas-deepcopy does not work. And the plain python deepcopy (from the copy module) seems to rely on a proper implementation of a __deepcopy__ by the NDFrame class